# SQL Query failing due SET Statement

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql

Whats wrong with this query?

```
UPDATE
  reinigung
SET
  `val1` = '[["Datum","20.04.2021","Kalenderwoche",16,"","",""],["","Gerdorf","","Hartmannsdorf1","","Hartmannsdorf2",""],["Zeit","Kennz. Tank","Fahrer","Kennz. Tank","Fahrer","Kennz. Tank","Fahrer"],["00:00","","","","","",""],["01:00","","","","","",""],["02:00","","","","","",""],["03:00","","","","","",""],["04:00","","","","","",""],["05:00","","","","","",""],["06:00","","","","","",""],["07:00","","","","","",""],["08:00","","","","","",""],["09:00","","","","","",""],["10:00","","","","","",""],["11:00","","","","","",""],["12:00","","","","","",""],["13:00","","","","","",""],["14:00","","","","","",""],["15:00","","","ssssssss","","",""],["16:00","","","","","",""],["17:00","","","","","",""],["18:00","","","","","",""],["19:00","","","","","",""],["20:00","","","ss","","",""],["21:00","","","","","",""],["22:00","","","sssss","","",""],["23:00","","","","","",""]]',
SET
  `val3` = 'test',
SET
  `val6` = 'herrsanderschmidt@gmail.com',
SET
  `val7` = '2021-04-20 06:05:01'
WHERE
  `val2` = '2021-04-20'
```

Comment: Are you sure thats SQL Server? Looks more like MySQL to me. And what error is it giving?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; it seems the error is around: 'SET `val3` = 'test', SET `val6` = 'herrsanderschmidt@gmail.com', SET `val7' at line 5 ... i cant figure why its failing

Comment: [Edit] it into your question. And confirm which RDBMS you are using.

Comment: I don't believe any SQL `UPDATE` statement requires more than one use of the keyword `SET` - I suggest checking the official documentation.

Comment: Are you sure this is `SQL Server` ? This does not looks like `SQL Server` statements to me, maybey `MariaDB` or `MySql` as asked here before. Please correct the DB tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use just one `set`  and use `comma` as separator for updating more than one value. and no need to enclose the column name with ``

```
UPDATE
  reinigung
SET
  val1 = '[["Datum","20.04.2021","Kalenderwoche",16,"","",""],["","Gerdorf","","Hartmannsdorf1","","Hartmannsdorf2",""],["Zeit","Kennz. Tank","Fahrer","Kennz. Tank","Fahrer","Kennz. Tank","Fahrer"],["00:00","","","","","",""],["01:00","","","","","",""],["02:00","","","","","",""],["03:00","","","","","",""],["04:00","","","","","",""],["05:00","","","","","",""],["06:00","","","","","",""],["07:00","","","","","",""],["08:00","","","","","",""],["09:00","","","","","",""],["10:00","","","","","",""],["11:00","","","","","",""],["12:00","","","","","",""],["13:00","","","","","",""],["14:00","","","","","",""],["15:00","","","ssssssss","","",""],["16:00","","","","","",""],["17:00","","","","","",""],["18:00","","","","","",""],["19:00","","","","","",""],["20:00","","","ss","","",""],["21:00","","","","","",""],["22:00","","","sssss","","",""],["23:00","","","","","",""]]',
,
  val3 = 'test',
,
  val6 = 'herrsanderschmidt@gmail.com',
,
  val7 = '2021-04-20 06:05:01'
WHERE
  val2 = '2021-04-20'
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I read so much that I missed that simple "one"-single-statement-fact. Thank you for your very fast help.